# Android abortBroadcast() works strange

Tags: android, android-emulator, sms

I make some program, which removes unwanted SMS from phone (by special filter).

It uses aborBroadcast() meted to stop SMS.

In emulator, it works okay, on some mobile phones (I tested with Android 2.2) too.

But in some phones (Samsung, 2.3.3) it does not stop SMS. And after my program removed, mobile receives ALL sms again, which was aborted.

My android.manifest code:

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsHandler" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647" >
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

My handler code:

```
if msgText.contains(GlobalVars.getInstance().getFilterText())) {
    abortBroadcast();
}
```

Maybe, somebody can advice me?

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of broadcasts, ordered and unordered. As far as I know, SMS is an unordered broadcast, and that is why you can't really abort it.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#Security

I am not sure when you say that it works on some devices. Ideally, it shouldn't for the SMS received broadcast.

Comment: I checked this by simple code: 

if (isOrderedBroadcast ()) sendToLog ("SMSIL", "Ordered."); else sendToLog ("SMSIL", "NOT Ordered.");

And broadcast is ordered.

Comment: Strange. BTW, I tried to abort that broadcast on a 2.3 emulator, and it doesn't work. I am quite sure, that you can't abort this broadcast. It might work on a few devices, as you mentioned.

Comment: One thing I noticed though, if you set the priority to 1000, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY, it seems to work on the emulator on which it wasn't. MAGIC!!!!

Comment: But beware, this might not play well with other apps, that listen to messages.

Comment: TigerBot would probably disagree. www.google.com/#q=tigerbot%20abort%20sms. In particular, www.networksecurity.com/the-tigerbot-malware-hits-android-phones/.